# Firestore security rules for digital transactions between users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Our app allows authenticated users to send and receive digital coins from each other in the app. Each user has a `coins` field which stores the current coin balance of a user. To transfer coins, we use firestore transactions at the sender's end to subtract the value of coins from the sender and then add the value to the receiver's balance. Hence, while the sender is logged in, they have to make writes to the receiver's document. This approach is insecure since we only check if the sender is logged in. This enables any authenticated user to have write access to another user's document. 
Is there a much better/secure approach to implement such kind of transactions between users and is it possible to handle the problem only using firestore security rules in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you wouldn't want to give users write access to each other user's documents, or even their own "wallets". Doing this type of transaction all in the client side (e.g. using Firestore iOS/Android/Web SDK)  will likely cause security issues down in the road. Of course, not many users will be aware of it, but tech savvy users who finds out that they have write access to other users' Firestore documents as long as they are signed in, will start deducting and taking coins from other users' wallets.

You will probably need to setup a server, or a script which will use Firebase Admin API to run transaction that you are talking about, so that it will be done in a black box according to your users' point of view.

Once you have the server up and running, client side app will then need to make calls to the server, preferably with auth tokens (e.g. Firebase Auth User's token), and ask for the transaction to run.